# How to delete a tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

what I want to achieve is to delete an HTML tag with JavaScript.

I have the following HTML tag:

```
<a class="fc-list-heading-main" data-goto="{"date":"2019-01-05","type":"day"}">5.Januar 2019</a>
```

What I want to achieve is to get rid of the link.
It should look something like this:

```
<class="fc-list-heading-main">5.Januar 2019</a>
```

This would be my JavaScript regex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var regex = /(<a class=\"fc-list-heading-main\" data-goto=\"\{\"date\":\"[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*\",\"[a-z]*\":\"[a-z]*\"}\">[0-9]*.[A-Z]*[a-z]*\w.[0-9]*<\/a>)/g;
s = s.replace(regex, '<p>Test</p>');

</script>
```

But somehow it does not work as expected.
Maybe someone knows what it is wrong here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Start by not using regex, but rather use the DOM. You're not working on html strings, right?

Comment: Your HTML tag is broken.

Comment: Where does `s` come from?

Comment: you are right: I am missing s.

Comment: Why do you replace with  `<p>test</p>`? It does not look like your desired output at all...

Comment: You cannot create invalid HTML elements with Javascript. That would invalidate the DOM, and Javascript would never allow for that to happen.

Comment: The output is an HTML string. This is the output: <a class="fc-list-heading-main" data-goto="{"date":"2019-01-04","type":"day"}">4. Januar 2019</a>

Comment: Again, `<class="fc-list-heading-main">5.Januar 2019</a>` is not a valid element and thus, cannot be created in Javascript.

Comment: @Bernd, that is invalid HTML. Look at the quotes...

Comment: As it currently is, this question makes no sense and I'm voting to delete it.

Comment: Ok, I see. So, there is no possibility to handle it correctly? Currently, the date is a link and I do not want the user to trigger this link.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem at issue here. If you want to disable a link's clickable functionality, the solution isn't to remove the "a" and leave the rest. The solution is to either set its onclick event handler to a function which calls `event.preventDefault()` or to simply set its href attribute value to an empty string.

Comment: *"So, there is no possibility to handle it correctly?"*: @Bernd, that's the wrong conclusion. First your question should be corrected. As it currently stands you do not represent the input in a valid way, and the output is not valid HTML either. Please take some time to consider this.

Answer (score 1):

For remove tag-attribute:

```
var content = document.querySelector(".fc-list-heading-main");
content.removeAttribute("data-goto");
```

For replace Element:

```js
var content = document.querySelector(".fc-list-heading-main");
var node = content.parentNode;
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.className = 'fc-list-heading-main';
a.innerHTML = content.innerHTML;
node.replaceChild(a, content);
```

```html
<a class="fc-list-heading-main" data-goto="{"date":"2019-01-05","type":"day"}">5.Januar 2019</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your regex does not work is the html is interpreted by the browser on load and builds a Document Object Model which is an object representation, all logic in the browser affects this model and as such your string manipulation will not affect the existing page unless you did this before the page is loaded and interpreted.

If you know the class you want, you can select the element, create a new element that is not a link and set its text from the old element, append the new element to the dom, and remove the old element.

This snippet should do what you want.

```
let class = 'fc-list-heading-main';

let old_element = document.getElementsByClassName(class);

let new_element = document.createElement("div");

new_element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;

new_element.classList.add(class);

document.body.insertBefore(new_element, old_element);

old_element.parentNode.removeChild(old_element);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry and I am an ....
I found an even simpler solution than manipulating something.

Although, I looked into the specification of FullCalendar, I could not find anything at first.

But now I saw this in my code:

```
navLinks: true,
editable: false,...
```

Setting navLinks: false solved the problem immediatly.

I am really sorry to have bothered you!